# Alamofire for loop returns empty array in Playgrounds

Tags: swift, alamofire

I've searched for the last hour and I can't seem to figure this out. I'm throwing in the towel and asking.

I have the following playground script below, and it prints an empty array.

I would like to return an array of custom objects when the function is called. I read that Alamofire is aynchronous, but I really don't know what to do at this point.

Thanks in advance!

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SWXMLHash
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation


PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)

class Tram {

    var arrivalInMinutes: Int?
    var tramDestinationEnglish: String?

    init(destination: String, arrivalTime: Int) {
        tramDestinationEnglish = destination
        arrivalInMinutes = arrivalTime

    }
}

func retrieveListOfTrams() -> [Tram] {

    var anyArray = [Tram]()

    Alamofire.request("https://hktramways.com/nextTram/geteat.php?stop_code=08W")
        .response { (response) in

            let xmlData = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)

            for elem in xmlData["root"]["metadata"].all {
                let tramArrival = elem.element!.attribute(by: "arrive_in_minute")!.text
                let tramDestination = elem.element!.attribute(by: "tram_dest_en")!.text
                anyArray.append(Tram(destination: tramDestination, arrivalTime: Int(tramArrival)!))

                }

            }
    return anyArray


}

print(retrieveListOfTrams())
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're returning the array before your request return a result, because as you read Alamofire have an asynchronous behavior. One way to solve this is by having a completion block that will only return the array after the result arrives:

```
func retrieveListOfTrams(completion: @escaping ([Tram]) -> Void) {

    var anyArray = [Tram]()

    Alamofire.request("https://hktramways.com/nextTram/geteat.php?stop_code=08W")
        .response { (response) in

            let xmlData = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)

            for elem in xmlData["root"]["metadata"].all {
                let tramArrival = elem.element!.attribute(by: "arrive_in_minute")!.text
                let tramDestination = elem.element!.attribute(by: "tram_dest_en")!.text
                anyArray.append(Tram(destination: tramDestination, arrivalTime: Int(tramArrival)!))

                }


            completion(anyArray)
            }   

}
```

Then you can call the function:

```
retrieveListOfTrams(completion: { anyArray in
    print(anyArray.description)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but now I'm encountering:

Playground execution failed: error: Playground.playground:36:13: error: closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape
            completion(anyArray)
            ^

Playground.playground:19:26: note: parameter 'completion' is implicitly non-escaping
func retrieveListOfTrams(completion: ([Tram]) -> Void) {
                         ^
                                     @escaping

Comment: I figured it out: func retrieveListOfTrams(completion: @escaping ([Tram]) -> Void)